# Paragraph in latex on overleaf disappearing

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting

I am new to LaTeX and wondering why one of my job experiences keeps disappearing when new text is added and it no longer neatly fits on a page. I would like to remove the space between page 1 and 2, but I am not sure how to get it all to fit. When I insert the `\newpage` command on line 68, I can get everything to move up, but then I lose the paragraph that proceeds the `\newpage` command. Does anyone have a solution on how to format this? Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section
\usepackage{hanging}


%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}


%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command


%Section: Research
\section{Research Experience}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 \textsc{July 2023-Current} & Clinical Research Coordinator (CRC), \textsc{University of California, San Francisco}\\&\textbf{Sleep and Mood Lab - Andrew Krystal, MD}\\
 \\&\emph{\textbf{Project:} Closed-Loop Deep Brain Stimulation for Major Depression (PReSiDio) ()}
 \\&\footnotesize{\textbf{{}DESCRIPTION:} The purpose of this study is to test a personalized approach to brain stimulation as an \\&\footnotesize intervention for depression. We use a surgically implanted device to measure each individual's brain \\&\footnotesize activity related to their depression. Then the team uses small electrical impulses to alter that brain \\&\footnotesize activity and measure whether these changes help reduce depression symptoms. This study is \\&\footnotesize intended for patients with major depression whose symptoms have not been adequately treated \\&\footnotesize with currently available therapies.\\&\footnotesize 
 \textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} As the, 
 }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 \textsc{May 2021-July 2023} & Lead Clinical Research Coordinator (CRC-2), \textsc{Stanford University,} Palo Alto, CA\\&\textbf{Biobehavioral Pediatric Pain Lab - Laura Simons, Ph.D}\\
 \\&\emph{\textbf{Project:} Signature for Pain Recovery in Teens - SPRINT (R61 NS114926)}
 \\&\footnotesize{\textbf{{}DESCRIPTION:} SPRINT is a multisite, international effort to uncover a biological signature predicting pain \\&\footnotesize recovery and persistence in teens with musculoskeletal pain. In collaboration with the University of \\&\footnotesize Toronto, Hospital for Sick Children (SickKids), and Cincinnati Children’s Hospital, we are using a novel  \\&\footnotesize machine learning technique to generate and test a elastic net model, opening doors for new screening \\&\footnotesize and treatment approaches. SPRINT participation consists of a blood draw, an hour-long MRI, sensory \\&\footnotesize testing, and parent and child questionnaires in person, and biweekly surveys for three months at home.\\&\footnotesize 
 \textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} As the Lead Coordinator of the SPRINT study, I manage and oversee study recruitment, \\&\footnotesize data collection, database management, and multiple team meetings. I work to standardize procedures, \\&\footnotesize coordinate blood transfers, and facilitate all data analysis by collating the data, merging, and cleaning it. \\&\footnotesize I assist with the writing and submission of progress reports to the NIH. Additionally, I am leading an \\&\footnotesize independent project on proposing a framework to examine diversity and representation in the recruitment \\&\footnotesize and participation of this study and future research.
 }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\
 \\&\emph{\textbf{Project:} Learning and Memory in Pediatric Chronic Pain (R01 HD083270)}
 \\&\footnotesize{\textbf{DESCRIPTION:} Given the influential role of learning and memory on pain outcomes in youth with \\&\footnotesize chronic pain, the goal of the current study is to examine the process of aversive learning in adolescents \\&\footnotesize with pain in comparison to healthy individuals. This study utilizes brain imaging (fMRI), psychophysical \\&\footnotesize (skin conductance), and saliva cortisol measures to assess functional circuit and physiological changes \\&\footnotesize associated with altered learning and memory patterns.\\&\footnotesize
 \textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} I have managed data analysis for this study and contributed to multiple manuscripts \\&\footnotesize and posters that are products of this study, including an independent project examining threat \\&\footnotesize learning in the cerebellum in youth with chronic pain and pain-free peers. 
 }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\
  \\&\emph{\textbf{Project:} Pain Rehabilitation Virtual Reality - PRVR (R21 AR079140)}
  \\&\footnotesize{\textbf{DESCRIPTION:} In collaboration with Stanford Children’s Health, Agile Physical Therapy, and California \\&\footnotesize Rehabilitation \& Sports Therapy, this randomized controlled trial will examine a novel approach to pain \\&\footnotesize management through the use of virtual reality (VR) technologies. We expect to address factors relevant \\&\footnotesize to chronic pain, including increasing range of motion, reducing pain-related fear of movement, and \\&\footnotesize improving the mind-body connection. VR tools for pain have shown promise in numerous research \\&\footnotesize studies and our mission is to continue to improve care for children and adolescents with chronic pain.\\&\footnotesize
 \textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} For this clinical trial I assisted with study start-up and initializing regulatory and IRB \\&\footnotesize contracts and protocols. I helped develop the protocol and best uses for VR in Physical Therapy. I trained \\&\footnotesize and oriented study staff and physical therapists. Additionally, I helped write the published protocol paper. 
  }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\ 
  \\&\emph{\textbf{Project:} Journey in Pain Care (K24 AR078945)}
 \\&\footnotesize{\textbf{DESCRIPTION:} Journey in Pain Care aims to conduct formative research to identify opportunities for \\&\footnotesize better care among youth with chronic pain and their families. Our goal is to characterize--with in-depth \\&\footnotesize interviews and longitudinal quantitative data--the experiences of youth living with chronic MSK pain and \\&\footnotesize their parents who are seeking and completing multidisciplinary pain care. The purpose is to highlight gaps \\&\footnotesize in care, communication, and understanding that should be further studied.\\&\footnotesize
 \textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} I trained to become a clinical interviewer on the study, assisted with regulatory affairs, \\&\footnotesize participated in bi-weekly group supervision to further develop and build upon clinical and research skills.
 }\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\  
 \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image: when I have the new job description on the top, the last paragraph of the next job is lost]

[image: when it all fits on the same page, all four paragraphs are there]

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to TeX StackExchange! You have a long long preamble, and as a general rule, the more things in your preamble you don't understand, the more likely something is to go wrong. Long preambles also make it harder for us to help you. Could you edit your question to trim it down to [just the code necessary to reproduce the problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: When I make guesses to complete your preamble, I end up with lots of errors about `Missing } inserted`.  You can't worry about text disappearing until you are error-free.

Comment: I notice also that you frequently try to format your résumé manually, for instance, by using ``\\`` to break lines in the same paragraph, or shrinking the font size over and over with `\footnotesize`. This can be cumbersome, and TeX is naturally good at doing formatting things without needing manual intervention. As another general rule, if your document body has a lot of manual formatting, there's probably a simpler way (and one that's less stressful to you).

Comment: Thank you all so much for your comments. I tried my best to cut the code as much  as I could. I can't reproduce the problem if all of the text fits on the same page so I have left the rest in.

Comment: But I don't have Fontin, and even if I comment that out, there's still 5 errors about a `Missing } inserted.`  Does this compile without any errors for you?

Comment: @Teepeemm It does compile for me. I have added images to show what it looks like.

Comment: But do you get any errors?  Like the fact that `\footnotesize{\textbf{{}DESCRIPTION:} The purpose of this study ...` never closes the first `{`?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: So, when the same code fails to compile unless it‘s run on Overleaf, that leaves only one suspect to me: Overleaf …

Comment: @Teepeemm I am using XeLaTeX 2022. When I try pdfLaTex or LaTex it won't compile.

Comment: "It does compile for me" that seems unlikely. Do you not have a red box with an error count above the pdf view?

Comment: Unrelated: `\footnotesize` is a switch that takes no argument. So, it should not be `\footnotesize{abc}`, but `{\footnotesize abc}` (the surrounding braces restrict the effect, if you want a complete table cell to be be affected, you can omit these).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach

Although this was originally a question about a vanishing paragraph, it seems helpful to take a step back and examine the approach to your CV on the whole. Rather than splitting your text into a left and right column with the standard LaTeX tables, the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package lets you create much nicer tables with much better support for multiple paragraphs. It's worth noting that you can simply type your experiences in normal sentences now; `\\&\footnotesize` is no longer necessary.

[image: A screenshot of the CV produced by the LaTeX code.]

### Notes

I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your preamble, as well as defining custom commands to help you to typeset your CV. Using commands like `\project`, `\desc`, and `\contrib` help you to save time and prevent typos. Here are a few notes about the changes I've made that may affect you:

- Your font wasn't available on my laptop, so you'll want to set the font to something available to you on your TeX distribution (in this case, Overleaf).
- On packages:

  - I deleted packages you weren't using—as I mentioned in my comment, you never want to know what bugs may be lurking simply because of a package loaded but left unused.
  - I replaced uncommon packages with more common ones like `geometry`, because it's easier to find online help for common packages. Some packages are also obsolete; for example, `color` has been superseded by `xcolor`, so it's not a good idea to load both.
  - `hyperref` should (almost) always be the last package loaded, since it significantly redefines much of LaTeX's core.
- The custom commands `\rolename`, `\institution`, `\labname` must always be placed together, in that order. Let's say you have an experience that was never associated with any institutions (e.g. you temporarily leave academia because a wizard persuades you to go on an adventure to destroy a tragic magic ring). You cannot simply omit `\institution`, or LaTeX will complain. Instead, you should simply leave the argument blank:

  ```
  \rolename{Lead adventurer}
  \institution{}
  \labname{Baggins Applied Mordor Research Group}
  ```
- Because the `j` option is a recent addition to `tabularray`, the code below will not compile on TeXlive distributions older than 2022. (A warning for those on the Internet who wish to reuse this code.)

### Code

```
%!TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                     % page setup
\usepackage{tabularray}                   % two column effect
\usepackage{titlesec}                     % custom section styles
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % colors
\usepackage{fontspec}                     % for TTF/OTF fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}                     % URLs and hyperlinks

\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\geometry{top = 5mm, bottom = 5mm, left = 5mm, right = 5mm} % change margins
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

% Change this to the font you want to use
\setmainfont{Segoe UI}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\newlength{\myparskip}
\setlength{\myparskip}{4pt}

\newcommand{\project}[1]{\textbf{Project:} \emph{#1}}
\newcommand{\desc}   [1]{\textbf{DESCRIPTION:} {\footnotesize#1}}
\newcommand{\contrib}[1]{\textbf{CONTRIBUTION:} {\footnotesize#1}\vspace{2\myparskip}}
\def\rolename#1\institution#2\labname#3{#1\textsc{, #2}\\\textbf{#3}}

\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}

\section{Research Experience}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{X[1,l]X[5,j]}
\textsc{July 2023-Current}
&
\rolename{Clinical Research Coordinator (CRC)}
\institution{University of California, San Francisco}
\labname{Sleep and Mood Lab - Andrew Krystal, MD}

\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}

\project{Closed-Loop Deep Brain Stimulation for Major Depression (PReSiDio) ()}

\desc{The purpose of this study is to test a personalized approach to brain stimulation as an intervention for depression. We use a surgically implanted device to measure each individual's brain activity related to their depression. Then the team uses small electrical impulses to alter that brain activity and measure whether these changes help reduce depression symptoms. This study is intended for patients with major depression whose symptoms have not been adequately treated with currently available therapies.}

\contrib{As the Lead Coordinator of the SPRINT study, I manage and oversee study recruitment, data collection, database management, and multiple team meetings. I work to standardize procedures, coordinate blood transfers, and facilitate all data analysis by collating the data, merging, and cleaning it. I assist with the writing and submission of progress reports to the NIH. Additionally, I am leading an independent project on proposing a framework to examine diversity and representation in the recruitment and participation of this study and future research.}

\\\textsc{May 2021-July 2023}
&
\rolename{Lead Clinical Research Coordinator (CRC-2)}
\institution{Stanford University, \textrm{Palo Alto, CA}}
\labname{Biobehavioral Pediatric Pain Lab - Laura Simons, Ph.D}

\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}

\project{Signature for Pain Recovery in Teens - SPRINT (R61 NS114926)}

\desc{SPRINT is a multisite, international effort to uncover a biological signature predicting pain recovery and persistence in teens with musculoskeletal pain. In collaboration with the University of Toronto, Hospital for Sick Children (SickKids), and Cincinnati Children’s Hospital, we are using a novel  machine learning technique to generate and test a elastic net model, opening doors for new screening and treatment approaches. SPRINT participation consists of a blood draw, an hour-long MRI, sensory testing, and parent and child questionnaires in person, and biweekly surveys for three months at home. }

\contrib{As the Lead Coordinator of the SPRINT study, I manage and oversee study recruitment, data collection, database management, and multiple team meetings. I work to standardize procedures, coordinate blood transfers, and facilitate all data analysis by collating the data, merging, and cleaning it. I assist with the writing and submission of progress reports to the NIH. Additionally, I am leading an independent project on proposing a framework to examine diversity and representation in the recruitment and participation of this study and future research.}

\project{Learning and Memory in Pediatric Chronic Pain (R01 HD083270)}

\desc{Given the influential role of learning and memory on pain outcomes in youth with chronic pain, the goal of the current study is to examine the process of aversive learning in adolescents with pain in comparison to healthy individuals. This study utilizes brain imaging (fMRI), psychophysical (skin conductance), and saliva cortisol measures to assess functional circuit and physiological changes associated with altered learning and memory patterns. }

\contrib{I have managed data analysis for this study and contributed to multiple manuscripts and posters that are products of this study, including an independent project examining threat learning in the cerebellum in youth with chronic pain and pain-free peers.}

\project{Pain Rehabilitation Virtual Reality - PRVR (R21 AR079140)}

\desc{In collaboration with Stanford Children’s Health, Agile Physical Therapy, and California Rehabilitation \& Sports Therapy, this randomized controlled trial will examine a novel approach to pain management through the use of virtual reality (VR) technologies. We expect to address factors relevant to chronic pain, including increasing range of motion, reducing pain-related fear of movement, and improving the mind-body connection. VR tools for pain have shown promise in numerous research studies and our mission is to continue to improve care for children and adolescents with chronic pain.}

\contrib{For this clinical trial I assisted with study start-up and initializing regulatory and IRB contracts and protocols. I helped develop the protocol and best uses for VR in Physical Therapy. I trained and oriented study staff and physical therapists. Additionally, I helped write the published protocol paper.}

% etc.
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Will be interesting, whether or not your approach works on Overleaf, too …

Comment: how does one get around the error messages - `Package fontspec Error: The font "Segoe UI" cannot be found.` and `Font TU/SegoeUI(0)/m/n/14.4="Segoe UI" at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ^^I\section{Research Experience}`

Comment: @jsbibra I stated in my answer already that Segoe UI is a font on my device, and not on Overleaf. After replacing Segoe UI with Roboto, it compiles on Overleaf without a problem. Given that OP used their own custom font on Overleaf, I assume they'll be able to adapt the code to suit their needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was incredibly helpful and I have been able to adapt this code. I truly appreciate it!

Comment: @ATM I'm happy to hear it helped! If you could mark my answer as Accepted by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons, I would be grateful :)